# How can I use only Local Notification and prevent the automatic popup using Firebase Messaging on Ios with Flutter

Tags: ios, flutter, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging, flutter-local-notification

I'm trying to use Local Notification on Flutter with an Ios device, it works, but the notification popup is shown two times, because one is from my `flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(...)` and one is showed automatically when a notification is catched.

In my case, I would like to show the notification only using Local Notifications, so I have to prevent showing the automatic notification. I've tried to send a notification without the "notification" object but only with a "data" object: in this case the automatic notification doesn't appears, but the event is not catched from the method `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {...})`, so also Local Notifications are not working.

On Flutter:

```
FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {


      await FirebaseMessaging.instance
          .setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(alert: false);

      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
          FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

      const IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
          IOSInitializationSettings();

      final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
          InitializationSettings(
        iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
      );
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
        initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (payload) async {
          print("selected");
        },
      );

      Future<String> _downloadAndSaveFile(
          String url, String fileName) async {
        final Directory directory =
            await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
        final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
        final http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
        final File file = File(filePath);
        await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
        return filePath;
      }

      final String bigPicturePath = await _downloadAndSaveFile(
          message.data['image'], 'bigPicture.jpg');
      final IOSNotificationDetails iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics =
          IOSNotificationDetails(attachments: <IOSNotificationAttachment>[
        IOSNotificationAttachment(bigPicturePath)
      ]);
      NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
          NotificationDetails(iOS: iOSPlatformChannelSpecifics);
      await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, message.data['title'],
          message.data['body'], platformChannelSpecifics,
          payload: 'item x');
    }

    print("Notification arrived");
  });
}
```

On server (PHP):

```
 $fields = array(

         'notification'    => [
            'content_avaible' => true,
            'body'     => $message,
            'title'    => $title,
            'priority' => "high",
            "image" =>  'image' => "https://foo.bar/image.png"
        ],
        "apns" => [

            "payload" => [
                "aps" => [
                    "mutable-content" => 1
                ]
            ],
            "fcm_options" => [
                 'image' => "https://foo.bar/image.png"
            ]
        ],
        'registration_ids'    => $alltokens,
        'data' => [
            'image' => "https://foo.bar/image.png"
        ],
    );
    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY_IOS,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
    $curlCall = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curlCall, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
    $result = curl_exec($curlCall);
    curl_close($curlCall);
```

Comment: Did you find anything for this?